# I am trying to make iterative API calls within a React element, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

So I am working on a personal project which gets an array of items from the DnD API and allows for alterations to their prices. What I am trying to do in this code is first, fetch the indexes of all the "equipment", then fetch the data each specific index so that I can get the name, description, price, etc of each individual item. I've been troubleshooting the code below for like 2 days, it fetches the indexes correctly, it goes to the page of each item and gets the name correctly, then the items are in the array correctly but the list items never appear on the client side.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const getItems = () => {

  const [items, setItems] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchCall = () => {
    fetch('https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/equipment/')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error("server error");
          }
      
        return response.json();}).then((response) => {
            const inedxes = response.results.map((item)=> item.index);
            var fetched = []
            inedxes.forEach((index) => {
                fetch('https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/equipment/'+index)
                .then((response) => {return response.json()}).then((response) => {
                   
                    fetched.push(response.name)
                })
            
    
            })
            setItems(fetched);  
            })
             .catch((error) => setError(error))
                  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    }

   useEffect(() => { fetchCall() }, []);

  return { items , error, loading };
};

const ItemHolder = () => {
  const { items, error, loading } = getItems();

  if (error) return <p>A network error was encountered</p>;
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  console.log("these are the items  "+items.toString())
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Items</h1>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item,i)=>{<li key={i}>{item}</li>})}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};


const HomePage = () => {
   



    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello from the main page of the app!</h1>
        <p>Here are some simple guidlines to use the site</p>

        <ItemHolder/>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default HomePage;
```

I want to know what the problem is, of course, but I would also welcome any advice about how I can  do this in a better way, like using Promise.allSettled() or how I can ensure that I only fetch data once, when the site is first mounted, but never again. Once I get this part functioning, I intent to create an item oject that has all the properties I want to track, and then map the data from the API onto a new instance of the object, and storing those in an array. However, if this is atypical/not best practices, feel free to let me know!

I have tried many different iteration methods, like map and for loops etc. Let me know what is best/normal

Comment: 1. Try writing this outside of React hooks first. Just make them regular functions. Once the functions do what you want, pull them back in React. 2. Learn about async/await and use them. 3. The core issue is probably that `forEach` does not do what you want here. `fetched` will only ge items until *after* setItems is called.

Comment: Ah thank you! Your advice is really helpful, but I'm just curious, for something like this is it best practice to use: .map, .forEach, Promise.allSettled, or a for loop?